# Deleting files created via CreateFileAsync?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-runtime

[*Microsoft on UWP apps - creating, writing, and reading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files)

My C# project creates jpegs dynamically using the CreateFileAsync() method, but I want to be able to delete the files I create during runtime as well and the only delete methods I could find were for deleting folders, not specific files. How do I go about this?

Comment: What's wrong with Windows.Storage.StorageFile.DeleteAsync() ?

Comment: @HarryJohnston DeleteAsync():
Deletes the current folder.

Comment: Can you post your code you are using?

Comment: Its highly suspecting that [StorageFile.DeleteAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.StorageFile#Windows_Storage_StorageFile_DeleteAsync) will delete folder.

Comment: The documentation for DeleteAsync says "deletes the current file".  If it is deleting the entire folder, you're probably using it wrong.  Post your code.

Comment: @Harry I read that exact doc before posting this question and somehow I read that it only deleted folders, not specific files. I must have been under the StorageFolder docs. Apologies for my misinterpretation. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In UWP app, if we need to delete a file, firstly we should get the file, then use the DeleteAsync() method to delete it.

For example, if you placed the files under the ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, using the following code to delete temp1.jpg.

```
private async void delete_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("temp1.jpg");
        if (filed != null)
        {
            await filed.DeleteAsync();
        }
}
```

Another way is to centralize the file path under one folder, simply we can delete all files under it instead of retriving and deleting files one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
var filename = "fileYouWantToDelete";
using (var isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
     isf.DeleteFile(fileName);
```

All you need to know where the file is placed;

Comment: I think `IsolatedStorageFile` is for Windows Phone 8.1 and below. UWP is `StorageFolder` and `StorageFile`